# Python Code List Defined

Tags: python, list, maya, defined

This is part of my python code. I keep having a problem with my lists and it says it is not defined. Can you help or explain to me how to fix that?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def changeXtransformVal(percentage=1.0, myList = myList):

    """
    Changes the value of each transform in the scene by a percentange.
    Parameters:
    percentage - Percentange to change each transform's value. Default value is 1.
    Returns:
    Nothing.
    """
    # The ls command is the list command. It is used to list various nodes
    # in the current scene. You can also use it to list selected nodes.
    transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
    found = False
    for thisTransform in transformInScene:
        if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
            found = True
            break
        else:
             found = False
    if found == False:
           sphere1 = cmds.polySphere()[0]
           cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
    # If there are no transforms in the scene, there is no point running this script
    if not transformInScene:
          raise RuntimeError, 'There are no transforms in the scene!'
    badAttrs = list('front','persp','side','top')
    # Loop through each transform
    for thisTransform in transformInScene:
          if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
              allAttrs = cmds.listAttr(thisTransform, keyable=True, scalar=True)
          allAttrs = [ i for i in badAttrs if i != "visibility" ]
          print allAttrs     
    for attr in myList:
               if attr in allAttrs:
                   currentVal = cmds.getAttr( thisTransform + "." + attr )
                   newVal = currentVal * percentage
                   cmds.setAttr(thisTransform + "." + attr, newval)
                   print "Changed %s. %s from %s to %s" % (thisTransform,attr,currentVal,newVal)
               else:
                   badAttrs.append(attr)

    if badAttrs:
        print "These attributes %s are not valid" % str()

myList = ("translateX", "translateY", "translateZ", "scaleX" )
changeXtransformVal(percentage=2.0, myList = myList)
```

Comment: Do you have a full traceback? Your error description is too vague for us to help you out.

Comment: Your indentation is *very* inconsistent. Can you clean it up please?

Comment: `list('front','persp','side','top')` is wrong, you're trying to pass 4 items to `list()`. Better use `['front','persp','side','top']`.

Comment: @hcwhsa: Since the code never modifies it, we can let it slide that it is really a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this is the first script I am writing as part of a school project and I don't know how to clean it up, I am still learning. This is the error I get every time i run the script                                                                                                                                   # Error: line 1: name 'myList' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
# NameError: name 'myList' is not defined #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving your function default parameters:

```
def changeXtransformVal(percentage=1.0, myList = myList):
```

These are evaluated when the function object is created, but at that time you have *no* `myList` object yet. You don't *have* to give these parameters default values, and you don't appear to use the values you do give.

If you don't need default values, use:

```
def changeXtransformVal(percentage, myList):
```

If you do need a default value for `percentage`, move the parameter to the end:

```
def changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=1.0):
```

and adjust your function call accordingly:

```
changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=2.0)
```

Note that you don't **have** to name parameters either; positional parameters work by position, and in this case `percentage=` is optional too.

Comment: Thank you so much I just need to tweak a few more things, thank you again